# how to export a processing sketch to pdf in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, processing

My starting point is a template I found on a blog (https://gist.github.com/1330065#file_p5_main.java):

```
<#assign licenseFirst = "/*">
<#assign licensePrefix = " * ">
<#assign licenseLast = " */">
<#include "../Licenses/license-${project.license}.txt">

<#if package?? && package != "">
package ${package};



</#if>
/**
 *
 * @author ${user}
 */

import processing.core.PApplet;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ${name} extends PApplet{

    @Override
    public void setup(){
        size(300, 300, P3D);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(){
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main(new String[]{ ${package}.${name}.class.getName()});
    }

}
```

This outputs to an applet. I tried to modify it with instructions I found here (http://www.processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1246034274.html) to create a pdf but could not get it to work.

Note: I have the pdf and itext libraries on the classpath.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question, for an export without a screen view, and single frame:

```
package Processing;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.pdf.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Controller extends PApplet {

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        size(300, 300, PDF, "filename.pdf");
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        exit();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main(new String[]{Processing.Controller.class.getName()});
    }
}
```